# Wix: Is communication between embeded HTML code and velo backend code possible?

Tags: javascript, velo

So I want to create a drag&drop feature on my website (not the file uploading way, but the way to move things around as a user). To achieve this, I am planning to use an HTML embed, which basically covers the whole site. This way, I am able to control everything on the website. Currently, I am creating a backend script to read the data out of my database. **Now I am asking myself whether I will be able to use that very script in my code? Or is my HTML embed completely isolated?** Thank you for your help!

```
import { sql } from '@velo/wix-data-sql-backend';

export async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const results = await sql("SELECT * FROM collection;");
        return results.payload.data.rows;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely communicate between an HTML Component and a page in Wix using the [`postMessage()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent/postmessage) and [`onMessage()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent/onmessage) functions.

As a side point, you might want to consider using a [Custom Element](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/customelement) instead of an HTML Component. You can also communicate between a Custom Element and a page using the [`setAttibute()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/customelement/setattribute) and [`on()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/customelement/on) functions.

Comment: How can I write HTML in that though?

Comment: Write HTML in what?

Comment: In that Custom Element? Because as far as I'm concerned it ist purely javascript.

Comment: Okay I found the answer to it. Thank you!